# how to include right protocol on dynamic pages

Tags: static-block, https, ee-1.14.2.1

Website can be accessed through http and https, we have http for the youtube videos as follow:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oaAfdePAWPI?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" height="347" width="617"></iframe>
```

I was wondering how we can have the protocole seperated to depend on http or https I know the way to do in backend but on static blocks I am not sure.

Comment: Please add your Magento version

Comment: Hi Prince I found the solution for it.

Comment: Ok, in this case accept your answer But you still haven't answered me of your Magento V ?

Comment: version is  enterprise 1.14.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this! if you remove the protocol it is smart enough to know what protocol it goes to like this:

```
 <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/oaAfdePAWPI?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1&amp;rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" height="347" width="617"></iframe>
```